# Getting CamelContext parameters from java bean

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have an issue with Spring and Camel.

I'm sorry I can't paste real code ...
So, I'm trying to get properties defined in the camel Context with a placeholder. But the properties are Empty.

```
<bean id="mySuperClass"
        class="com.lol.rofl.MySuperClass">
</bean>
<camelContext id="blablabla" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<propertyPlaceholder id="myProp"
        location="classpath:camel/contexts/myprops.properties" />
....
Some fantastique code that use the properties and works.
....
</camelContext>
```

the .java :

```
public class MySuperClass implements CamelContextAware
{

    public void getCCProperties()
    {
           final Map<String, String> camelContextProperties = camelContext.getProperties();
            crawlerOutputDirectory = camelContextProperties.get("my.super.pro");
    }
}
```

I just think I'm not trying the right way, thanks for you help

---

**SOLUTION**

Properties in placeHolders can be found this way :

```
camelContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{" + propertyName + "}}");
```

ex : `camelContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{output.directory}}");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the javadoc of the methods, `getProperties` on CamelContext is not for property placeholder. Use `resolvePropertyPlaceholders` for property placeholder

javadoc for CamelContext: http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html